# How to execute Python and .bat scripts from a web page on local machine

Tags: javascript, php, python, batch-file

I want create a web page which has links of different Python scripts and .bat files, which can call different .bat file with different parameters specified in web-form.

Purpose of this web page is to only use on a local machine.

I tried with JavaScript and PHP, but I am not able to open any local .bat or .py file on machine. How can I do this?

Comment: you can download a wierd mime, one not used aready, and tell the browser you want to always open that type of file.  then associate the bat file with that type (ch) or, browse to the bat directly to open the mime the first time(ff). from then on, triggering the same download will execute your application. when associating the app, you may have to type "*" in the file name slot of the file browse dialog to reveal more than just EXEs, but it will still work with any executable file that accepts command-line args. the download data (if needed) is passed behind a temp file path to the cmd.

Comment: Improving formatting and fixing typos. Changed some tags and used a better title

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about exec @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
<?php
exec("batfilename.bat");
?>
```